# How to load historical JSON files into date partitioned apache hive table?

Tags: json, apache-spark, hive

Here is my requirement,

- I have bunch of JSON files with no date tag in it.
- Date is available in file name(Ex: PLV_sample1_**01-12-2018**.json).
- I have total of 40K JSON historical files from different dates.

May i know how can i load this data into date partitioned hive table by extracting date from filename?

Answer (score 0):

Here you cannot directly create dataframe by reading json file using json reader API because your table is partitioned based on date and date object is not present in your Json file.

But you can create a list of json file name and iterate over it to extract date from json file.

I hope your all json file Name structure is same. considering above
create one object which holds all your file Name like below

val obj = List("PLV_sample1_01-12-2018.json","PLV_sample1_02-12-2018.json","PLV_sample1_03-12-2018.json",
      "PLV_sample1_04-12-2018.json","PLV_sample1_05-12-2018.json")

val date = obj.map(x => x.split("_").last.substring(0,10)).foreach(println) // all your date will come in this object

NOTE: As I can see you have around 40k file, so if collection is big then better to call "toIndexedSeq" then performance will be better O(1)
val date = obj.toIndexedSeq.map(x => x.split("_").last.substring(0,10)).foreach(println)

Now you have all date value

create a sparkSession first then
val df = spark.read.json("Path to json file")

and using withColumn method you can add date as a column in your DF and while writing to sink

df.write.format("storage format").partitionBy("date").save("path to sink")

Note: If Hive is your sink and table is external then give hive external table path. OR you can make use of saveAsTable("Table name"). Here spark will create hive table and load data with date as partition column.